# Hi, I am trying to import/install requests and beautiful soup in VScode but the following doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, python-import

This is the code that works for me in Jupyter Notebooks, but for some reason it doesn't in VSCode. I keep getting the error 'No module named 'requests''

`import requests`

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Is anybody able to help?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @blackbrandt I don't think so, I've just downloaded VS Code and installed Python on it.

Comment: Can you please add the error you get ? Also do a `pip list` and check if the two modules are getting listed.

Comment: So I have installed requests and bs4 in the command prompt using the code here: ``python -m pip install requests`` but now I get this error:  "BeautifulSoup" is not accessedPylance

Comment: @Alex Markides You need to install BeautifulSoup with the command `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: thank you -  that's working now!

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the requests module on your computer.

Type  `pip install requests` or `python -m pip install requests` in your command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
Look at your corner in the down left side.
If that is Python 3.9 or some update version like this

[image]

Change this to base: Conda and it will work.

[image]

Now you will not see the error.

It worked for me.